# How to read NFC reader on client from server using C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to read the NFC reader using C# (I have written a bit of code to read the expected value coming out from NFC reader).

But in the future I have to shift my code to a Windows server, but my NFC reader will be attached to a Windows client machine (more than 1 client machine). So basically I have to read the NFC Reader on client machine with my C# code which will be linked to my one web application on server.

Do I need to do port monitoring of all the clients connected to the server? How should I achieve this? Is there any other way?

Comment: Why can't your client application read the NFC and send the data to to the server?

Comment: What do you mean by a client application ?.I dont have any application installed on client .Client machine can navigate web application through web browser. And the web application is hosted on a server which is HTML 5 application

Comment: Your question is unclear. [Edit] your question to make it clearer, although it sounds like you may need to do more research into the subject first.

Comment: You cannot use code running on the *server* to access hardware on the *client*.

Comment: Per the existing scenario, most of the market available NFC Readers are USB based and still there is no easy way to access the commercially available USB based NFC reader through WebUSB(refer https://wicg.github.io/webusb/). Instead you can try the DIY version through Arduino as in https://github.com/gdarchen/webusb-arduino-nfc.